# Can GEE handle small unaccounted clusters in data?

Tags: correlation, survey, epidemiology, generalized-estimating-equations, confounding

A survey is being administered in a resource intensive setting. A 2-phase study design will be implemented using cases and controls identified by a certain behavior (say, smoking) and they will be screened for SNP information on a number of biomarkers for disease associated with the negative health outcomes associated with that behavior.

The problem is that in this setting there are potentially large numbers of first degree relatives living in the same household, which would contribute to environmental factors influencing prevalence of the behavior or outcome risk independent of behavior (say, second hand smoking). Due to confidentiality reasons, it was decided not to collect residence.

Assuming we could capture auxiliary exposure independent of behavior (such as "how many cigarettes are smoked in the same room as you in a week's time?), this could account for confounding by residence. Then relatedness would only be a unaccounted for cluster.

How efficient is a GEE with independent covariance structure at accounting for small numbers of unaccounted for clusters in the data? If we use these data, can we come up with a recommended sample size difference accounting for and not accounting for relatedness to achieve a target power for determining association with disease status and behavior? I appreciate references to scholarly publications directly addressing this issue from related applied problems.